# how to fetch last 3 months data in hive table

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm using below command to fetch last 3 months data from hive.

select * from xyz where creat_ts between '2017-01-06 00:00:00' and '2017-03-06 23:59:59';

how to fetch last 3 months data in hive without using between keyword.

Comment: if your hive collumn is of datatype TIME STAMP , why don't you use creat_ts>'2017-01-06 00:00:00 and creat_ts<='2017-03-06 23:59:59' ?

Answer (score 0):

if your column `creat_ts` of type `timestamp`  you can write your query like

```
select * from xyz where from_unixtime(creat_ts) > '2017-01-05' and from_unixtime(creat_ts) < '2017-03-07';
```

or if column is of type `datetime` or `date` then your query would simply be

```
select * from xyz where creat_ts > '2017-01-05' and creat_ts < '2017-03-07';
```

Hope this will help

Comment: time stamp is in format "2016-12-14T14:20:14-0700" . I need to get last 2 month data using format like unix_timestamp(string date) - 60 days instead of explicitly mentioned date1 and date2.